# Message.obtain() in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, memory, kotlin-coroutines

So i have  a service that send a message by messenger on a remote process and recevice that in app's process

```
                messenger.send(
                    Message.obtain().apply {
                        data = Bundle().apply {
                            putString("value", "some random value")
                        }
                    }
                )
```

and when receive that,i use a coroutine to run a block of code in worker thread pool:

```
         inner class IncomingHandler() : Handler() {
             override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
                val msgData = msg.data
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + SupervisorJob()).launch {
                    Log.d("TEST", "${msg.data===msgData}") // false
                }
            } 
        }
```

I found out that **msgData** and **msg.data** is not pointing at the same object. **msgData** is the bundle from a message that i sent earlier but **msg.data** is a completly empty bundle.

When i use **msg** in coroutine( another thread) its like **msg** reference to another object i dont know how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Message` objects are shared in a global pool, to try and avoid creating too many new objects. From the docs:

> `public static Message.obtain()`
>
> Return a new Message instance from the global pool. Allows us to avoid allocating new objects in many cases.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message#obtain()

After the message is processed by the `Handler`, it gets returned to the pool. Its state will be cleared so that the same `Message` object can be used again. Because of this, you should never try to access a `Message` object after its handler has completed.

Your coroutine runs in a separate thread, after the call to `handleMessage()` has already completed. That means that by the time the coroutine runs, the message may have already been recycled and returned to the pool.

Comment: Oh yeah thank you,thats why all the property of message is set to default